# Ошибка использования CTE

Tags: sql-server

Есть следующая функция для MS SQL Server 2019:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_supplier_balance_holder]
(
    @SupplierId int
)
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result int
    ;WITH cte1(AgentId , ParentId, IsBalanceHolder) AS
    (
        SELECT
            s.NUMBER,
            s.FK_PARENT_ID,
            s.IS_CREDIT_LIMIT_HERE
        FROM
            dbo.SUPPLIERS s WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE 
            s.NUMBER = @SupplierId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            s.NUMBER,
            s.FK_PARENT_ID,
            s.IS_CREDIT_LIMIT_HERE
        FROM
            dbo.SUPPLIERS s WITH(NOLOCK)
            JOIN cte1 ON s.NUMBER = cte1.ParentId
    )

    SELECT TOP 1 @result = AgentId FROM cte1 AS [result]
    WHERE [result].IsBalanceHolder = 1
RETURN @result;
END
```

Как видно, при каждом вызове функции создается CTE. При этом иногда функция отрабатывает без ошибок, иногда вылетает "Неразрешенное имя cte1". При этом происходит это случайно. Хотелось бы понять, в чем может быть проблема. Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с подобным и может что-то сказать по этому поводу? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: выполняется то от одного и того же юзера?

Comment: @teran, да,  от одного и того же

Comment: А если убрать schemabinding?

Comment: "иногда" это как часто? можно руками ф5 нажимая при вызове получить? и например повторить, без обертки в функцию

Comment: Проблема связана со scalar function inlining, уверен примерно на 146%. Попробуйте установить последние обновления сервера (на текущий момент CU 15). Если не поможет, попробуйте поработать с отключенным инлайном `ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING = OFF;`

Comment: @teran, да, можно и с помощью F5

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, можете немного подробнее сказать, в чем именно проблема? Гугление о  scalar function inlining особо ничего не дало) Буду благодарен!

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, скажу более  точно: да, есть scalar function inlining, и, вроде бы, это даже хорошо. Но мне хотелось бы понять, в чем здесь может быть проблема из-за scalar function inlining

Comment: [Scalar UDF Inlining issues in SQL Server 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d) - список фиксов и исключений по этой теме. В основном инлайнинг работает нормально, но бывают с ним странные баги типа вашего. Так что лучше как минимум поставить последний CU, с высокой вероятностью это решит проблему.